# Wrapping a C function in Cython which has non-stanard types as arguments

Tags: python, c++, cython

I am trying to wrap a C++ function that has arguments of type uint32_t, which can be found in the cstdint library. Let's say the C++ file looks like

cppfile.cpp:

```
#include <cstdint>

int foo(uint32_t x){
    return 1;
}
```

How do I wrap this in a Cython .pxd file? If x was just a normal integer, I would do

```
cdef extern from "cppfile.cpp":
    cdef int foo(int x)
```

But how do I do this when x is of type uint32_t? How do I obtain the uint32_t as a type in cython?

Comment: Is it a C function or a C++ function ? The title says C function, whereas the description paints a different picture.

Comment: [rtfm](https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-declare-numeric-or-integer-c-types)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a question answered in the [FAQ of cython](https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-declare-numeric-or-integer-c-types)

```
from libc.stdint cimport uint32_t

cdef extern from "cppfile.cpp":
    cdef int foo(uint32_t x)
```